# Load Symfony2 translations from custom directory

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, translation

as we all know Symfony2 looks for translations in these directories:

```
YourBundle\Resources\translations\ - here lot of .yml files
app\Resources\translations\ - here lot of .yml files
```

But what if I want to put my translations into

`MyBundle\Resources\translations\2015_04_23\ - and lot of .yml files will lay here`

I read docs but didnt see solution, it is possible? Maybe I ommit part of doc? Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be documented: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/custom_formats.html#components-translation-custom-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it's documented here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/custom_formats.html#components-translation-custom-loader

You do exactly the same as in the doc but when you use your translation loader, you add your translation by choosing yourself the directory :

```
$translator->addResource('my_format', __DIR__.'/translations/messages.txt', 'fr_FR');
```

(simply need to replace `__DIR__` with your wisely chosen directory, try to be careful if you, for example, use dynamics files : you should use for example a service to be sure your code will be easily maintainable)